# ORA_ASPNET_MEM_GETALLUSERS must be declared ASP.NET MVC Oracle Providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle11g, odp.net

As per [this tutorial from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/usingoracleprovidersaspnet2/UsingOracleProvidersforASPNet.htm), I am trying to set up my application to use the Oracle Membership, Role and state providers. While in the process of setting up the membership, using the ASP.NET Admin tool, I get the following error when clicking on the "Security" tab:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 15: PLS-00201: identifier 'ORA_ASPNET_MEM_GETALLUSERS' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

[image]

I can confirm that the identifier DOES in fact exist in the DB.

[image]

I am using the exact same credentials for the membership provider as I do for the rest of the site and also when connection to SQL Developer.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone was wondering, the solution was to first do the following steps [outlined here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/installation.htm#CHDCBFFJ)

Grant privileges to the new database user so it can create the schema and store web site state for the ASP.NET providers:
 Set Object type to USER and set User to ASPNET_DB_USER (or your user of choice).
The generally required privileges include:

> 1. Change notification
> 2. Create job
> 3. Create procedure
> 4. Create public synonym
> 5. Create role
> 6. Create session
> 7. Create table
> 8. Create view
> 9. Drop public synonym
> 10. Unlimited Tablespace