# Oracle session state store

Tags: asp.net, oracle, session-state

I'm tasked with finding a way to track a users session across 2 sites. The site was created before I had any input and they created one site for documentation, one for the data and made them intertwined and look the same.  This has been in use for many years so I'm unable to change this.  I know I can use a query string across both sites as an indicator of the user.  I did find the oracle session state store: [Oracle Session State Store](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14435_01/win.111/e10928/OracleSessionStateStoreClass.htm#BABIBEBA)

I followed the directions listed with updating my web.config file, but I'm not sure how to actually use the session state object.  I was unable to find any example code of how to implement the actual session state.  I do get this error when running the site:

```
Parser Error Message: ORA-06550: line 1, column 15:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ORA_ASPNET_SESSNAPP_GETAPPID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Source Error:

    Line 21:       <providers>
    Line 22:         <add name="MyOracleSessionStateStore"
    Line 23:              type="Oracle.Web.SessionState.OracleSessionStateStore, 
    Line 24:              Oracle.Web, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, 
    Line 25:              PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"


Source File: C:\tempApp\web.config    Line: 23
```

It looks like I need to have rights to "ORA_ASPNET_SESSNAPP_GETAPPID", but I am unable to find any information on that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Corp. has decided to not document these objects because they must only be used using Windows interfaces.

If you get this error, it is possible that some setup step is missing.
See [ORA_ASPNET_MEM_GETALLUSERS must be declared ASP.NET MVC Oracle Providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592208/ora-aspnet-mem-getallusers-must-be-declared-asp-net-mvc-oracle-providers).

Comment: Thank you pifor, the documentation is hard to find and understand.  How does the session know if the user switches sites who they are?  I know how the C# session works, but how does the oracle approach work?